# std::shared_mutex not scaling with threads doing lock_shared()

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a simple program to test out the performance of `std::shared_mutex` across a number of threads looping `lock_shared()`. But from the result, it doesn't seems to scale with more threads added, which doesn't really make sense to me.

**You may argue it's because the `stopFlag` limiting the performance, so the second for loop a test for increment a local counter, which is almost perfect scaling in the beginning**

The result in the comments are compiled with `MSVC` with `Release` flag.

```cpp
int main()
{
    const auto threadLimit = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1; //for running main() 
    struct SharedMutexWrapper
    {
        std::shared_mutex mut;
        void read()
        {
            mut.lock_shared();
            mut.unlock_shared();
        }
    };
    /*Testing shared_mutex */
    for (auto i = 1; i <= threadLimit; ++i)
    {
        std::cerr << "Testing " << i << " threads: ";
        SharedMutexWrapper test;
        std::atomic<unsigned long long> count = 0;
        std::atomic_bool stopFlag = false;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(i);
        for (auto j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            threads.emplace_back([&] {unsigned long long local = 0; while (!stopFlag) { test.read(); ++local; } count += local;  });
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 1 });
        stopFlag = true;
        for (auto& thread : threads)
            thread.join();
        std::cerr << count << '\n';
    }
/*
Testing 1 threads: 60394076
Testing 2 threads: 39703889
Testing 3 threads: 23461029
Testing 4 threads: 16961003
Testing 5 threads: 12750838
Testing 6 threads: 12227898
Testing 7 threads: 12245818
*/
    for (auto i = 1; i <= threadLimit; ++i)
    {
        std::cerr << "Testing " << i << " threads: ";
        std::atomic<unsigned long long> count = 0;
        std::atomic_bool stopFlag = false;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(i);
        for (auto j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            threads.emplace_back([&] {unsigned long long local = 0;  while (!stopFlag) ++local; count += local; });
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 1 });
        stopFlag = true;
        for (auto& thread : threads)
            thread.join();
        std::cerr << count << '\n';
    }
/*
Testing 1 threads: 3178867276
Testing 2 threads: 6305783667
Testing 3 threads: 9388659151
Testing 4 threads: 12472666861
Testing 5 threads: 15230810694
Testing 6 threads: 18130479890
Testing 7 threads: 20151074046
*/
}
```

Comment: You're testing the effect on contention on the locks -- more contention == slower.  Not surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing a read lock on a shared mutex modifies the state of that mutex. All your threads do nothing but try to change the state of the same object, the shared mutex. So of course this code is going to scale poorly.

The point of a shared mutex is to allow accesses to shared data that is not modified to scale. You have no accesses to shared data that is not modified. So you aren't measuring any of the beneficial properties of a shared mutex here.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I would like to mention that there are some algorithms to reduce contention for shared locks, e.g. [BRAVO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01553).